# Program isn't accepting longer inputs or multiple lines?

Tags: c

When I type "add", it asks for my bank account, name and address. However, if a type a long name with spaces it goes back to the loop and does not collect the address. Also the address should accept multiple lines from the input, but after I enter 'enter' it goes back to the loop and loops 3 times and displays *Error: Invalid option. Please, renter a valid menu option.* Any help would be amazing, thanks a lot.
It was working normally until I added other parameters for bankMenu and addRecord, before I only had struct record was a parameter.

```
struct record {
  int accountno;
  char name[25];
  char address[80];
  struct record * next;
};

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include "record.h"

void getaddress(char[], int);enter code here
void bankMenu(struct record * , int, char[], char[]);
int addRecord(struct record ** , int, char[], char[]);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  struct record * start = NULL;
  int account = 0;
  char name[25];
  char address[80];

  bankMenu(start, account, name, address);

  return 0;
}

void bankMenu(struct record * start, int account, char name[], char address[]) {
  /*Display the menu options */

  char input[30];
  size_t len;
  int loopStopper = 1;

  printf("~ Dear Customer, Welcome to the Bank of Hawaii. ~\n");

  while (loopStopper != 0) {
    printf("Select your transaction.\n");
    printf("\tadd: Add a new record in the database.\n");
    printf("\tquit: Quit the program.\n");
    scanf("%s", input);

    len = strlen(input);

    if (strncmp(input, "add", len) == 0) {
      printf("You have chosen to add a new record.\n");
      addRecord( & start, account, name, address);

    } else if (strncmp(input, "quit", len) == 0) {
      printf("You have decided to quit. Thank you.\n");
      loopStopper = 0;

    } else {
      printf("Error: Invalid option. Please, renter a valid menu option.\n");
    }
  }
}

int addRecord(struct record ** start, int account, char name[], char address[]) /*add a record*/ {
  int c;

  printf("Enter your account number:\n");
  scanf("%d", & account);

  do {
    c = getchar();
  } while (c != EOF && c != '\n');

  printf("Enter your name:\n");
  fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);

  printf("Enter your residential address:\n");
  getaddress(address, sizeof address); /*call function to get address and allow multiple lines*/

  return 1;
}

void getaddress(char address[], int limit) { /*function to get address and accept multiple lines*/
  int size = 0;

  while (fgets(address + size, limit, stdin)) {

    if (strlen(address + size) == 1)

      break;

    size = strlen(address);

    limit = limit - size;

    if (limit <= 0)

      break;

  }
}
```

Comment: Please give a log of the exact input and result.

Comment: `fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);` won't work. `sizeof name` gives `sizeof(char *)` and not the size of the array because arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function. Need to pass array sizes into the function.

Comment: After I type "add":   You have chosen to add a new record.
Enter your account number:
234567
Enter your name:
david luigi
Enter your residential address:
12345 maksnka
Select your transaction.
        add: Add a new record in the database.
        show: Print information about a record using the account # as a key.
        printall: Print all records in the database.
        find: Find record(s) with a specified account #.
        delete: Delete existing record(s) from the database using the account @kaylum

Comment: @kaylum You are right. It's fixed now!